# Is it possible to link a xcframework (FirebaseCore.xcframework) using cmake for Xcode 11 without pod? I can't find an example

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, cocos2d-x, xcode11

Try to integrate firebase 6.23.0 using CMake in cocos2d-x 4.0 is there an example availiable.

Comment: Not sure how to do it with cmake, I just dragged xcframework to cocos2dx 4.0 project, and in xcode-> project Settings, updated Build System from Legacy build System to New Build System(Default). Everything worked perfect.

Comment: I can use your answer, but i want to make the projects automaticaly using cmake.

Answer (score 1):

You can do below work around to use latest firebase sdks.

Try to use framework directly from specific folder. For example for FirebaseCore add framework directly FirebaseCore.framework from this directory

```
"FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/FirebaseCore.framework"
```

Add all frameworks from specific arch like for iOS device ios-armv7_arm64.

Then in cmake you will need to add frameworks like you add any other iOS native framework.

```
set(ios_frameworks 
FirebaseCore
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
FirebaseInstallations
FirebaseInstanceID
FirebaseMessaging
GoogleAppMeasurement
FIRAnalyticsConnector
FirebaseAnalytics
GoogleDataTransport
GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
GoogleUtilities
PromisesObjC
Protobuf
nanopb
FirebaseCrashlytics
)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's enough context in this answer, because after calling `set` you would still need to link the library with `target_link_libraries`. For example, see the following CMakeLists file: https://github.com/wrld3d/wrld-example-app/blob/master/ios/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

For now i used (found samwhere else) not working for xcframework:

```
MESSAGE(STATUS "Firebase in: ${CMAKE_FIREBASE}")
macro(find_host_library)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER)
    find_library(${ARGN})
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
endmacro(find_host_library)

macro(ADD_FRAMEWORK fwname appname)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "MACRO ADD_FRAMEWORK firebase ${CMAKE_FIREBASE} ${fwname} ${appname} !!!")
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER)
    find_library(FRAMEWORK_${fwname}
        NAMES ${fwname}
        PATHS ${CMAKE_FIREBASE}  
        PATH_SUFFIXES framework xcframework
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
    if( ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${fwname}-NOTFOUND)
        MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework ${fwname} not found")
    else()
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${appname} ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}})
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Framework ${fwname} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
    endif()
endmacro(ADD_FRAMEWORK)

if(IOS)
    SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -ObjC") # Necessary for Firebase

endif()
SET(CMAKE_FIREBASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics)

ADD_FRAMEWORK(FIRAnalyticsConnector  ${APP_NAME})
ADD_FRAMEWORK(FirebaseAnalytics ${APP_NAME})
ADD_FRAMEWORK(FirebaseCore ${APP_NAME})
#ADD_FRAMEWORK(FirebaseCoreDiagnostics ${APP_NAME})
```

The FirebaseCore FrameWork is a .xcframework and give a "not found" error.

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQLRI.png)

Comment: Is there anyone who knows if it is posible with CMAKE?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: For now i made two folders: Firebase.simulator and Firebase.hardware. I copied the ios-armv7_arm64/FirebaseCore.framework to the root of the Firebase.hardware folder, and copied the ios-i386_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseCore.framework to the root of the Firebase.simulator (same for all the xcframeworks i need).  The project is refering to the Firebase folder. When i build voor simulator i rename the Firebase.simulator to Firebase and when i compile for hardware i rename the Firebase.hardware to Firebase.